# virtualbox install somehow corrupted

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have a HP Zbook laptop running CentOS7.1.  I use it to run an Ubuntu 14.04 VM, which has been working fine for quite a while.

This morning I saw some weird problems (can't remember exactly what), so I rebooted, and it wouldn't show the Gnome login page (I saw the line vector "7" in the background).  I eventually figured out how to get the text login prompt, and it showed that a recent yum update of VirtualBox appeared to be aborted.  I did "yum-complete-transaction" and that appeared to complete.

I don't know why that would block the graphical login, but when I rebooted after that, I got the login page back and everything seemed fine, until I tried to run my VM.

When I did that, I got a dialog saying this:

```
Failed to start the virtual machine ...
Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!
```

What can I do now?

Comment: Ok, well, I'm not sure what happened, but I ended up doing "yum remove" on the virtualbox package, reinstalling it, and then reinstalling the extension pack, and now my vm runs again.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means you don't have the VB Extension Pack. USB 2.0 support is provided by the VB Extension Pack.

So you either:

a) install the VirtualBox Extension Pack (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

b) reconfigure your virtual machine to not require USB 2.0 (in the VirtualBox Manager) click on your machine name -> Settings -> USB -> choose USB 1.0 (OHCI) Controller instead of USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller.